# google map - error in iframe

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm using google map to...show map on my website.

when I run the file (html) I see the map. when I run my website and call the map file from iframe I see 
http://80.179.226.44/~israelig/sites/exmytrip/tempmap.php

```
error: "Oops! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details."
```

**IFRAME:**

```
    <div id="map-canvas" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <iframe style="border-radius: 5px; width: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="itinMap.html"></iframe>
    </div>
```

**itinMap.html file:**

```
<div id="map"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var map;
        var elevator;
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], myOptions);

        var addresses = ['rome', 'milan'];

        for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
            $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
                var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map
                });

            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Share the error shown in console of the browser

Comment: @GauravKP, i have no idea how to show it to you...

Comment: @GauravKP - please see the url i added above

Comment: This service requires an API key.  For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key"

Comment: Use Chrome/ IE or Firefox and Press F12, to check error log. Seems you had not provided API Keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Error is because you had not provided API Keys.

**Source Google**

> The script element that loads the API has no API key. Please make sure
>   you include a valid API key as a key parameter. You can generate a new
>   API key on the Google API Console.
>
> Getting API Keys
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

- MissingKeyMapError

> The script element that loads the API is missing the required
>   authentication parameter. If you are using the standard Maps
>   JavaScript API, you must use a key parameter with a valid API key. If
>   you are a Premium Plan customer, you must use either a client
>   parameter with your client ID or a key parameter with a valid API key.

**To Debug Such JS Error**

Use Chrome, IE or Firefox and Press F12, to check error log.